# Arrayfield in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

my code:

```
pagerange_str_array = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                 blank=True, default=list()))
```

docs example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

```
board = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
        size=8,
    ),
    size=8,
)
```

docs - size: This is an optional argument.

error message:

```
DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

But none of these work:  default={}, '{}',or {''}
They all get the same error message.

docs: If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as list (for an empty default) or a callable that
returns a list (such as a function)

But none of these work either: default=list, list(). null=True (my original code) also does not work.

All these examples give the same error. I have seen non-Django solutions on the web, but what is an example of code that works in Django?! Thanks.

Comment: This is probably not the issue, but your `default` is in the `CharField`, not in the `ArrayField`.

Comment: I've never seen it done that way, but perhaps a good tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you are talking about `1-dim` array, and it should be smth like that:

```
board = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
        size=8,
    ),
    size=1,
)
```

so in your case smth like:

```
pagerange_str_array = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    ),
    size=1
)
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I thought if there was nothing there about size, then by default the dimensions would match.